# Migration error when using jSON field on MariaDB

Tags: laravel, migration, mariadb, laravel-6

After trying to add a new jSon column to my Users table, I am getting an error related to field size. I blame MariaDB because they can't see the future, but is there a way to override this error without changing my field type to BLOB or TEXT?

Here is my up method in the migration:

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table( 'users', function( Blueprint $table ){
    $table->json( 'options' )->nullable();
  } );
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
In Connection.php line 669:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row siz
  e for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check t
  he manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs (SQL: alter table `users` add `opti
  ons` json null)


In PDOStatement.php line 129:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row siz
  e for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check t
  he manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs


In PDOStatement.php line 127:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row siz
  e for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check t
  he manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

Comment: Check if the other columns aren't unnecessarily large and possibly shrink them.

Comment: Please provide the generated `CREATE TABLE` so we can diagnose what Laravel did wrong.

Comment: Sadly I cannot recreate the error anymore, I opted to move my database to MySQL 8 and everything worked correctly. I will not make the same mistake of using MariaDB in the future. jSON is a great way to manage optional information in a database and the developer's denial of this reality is just unacceptable for me.